# print a calendar for a given date in Ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime, calendar

I am trying to create a method that takes user entered month and year and prints out an accurate calendar for the month and year.  I am about halfway through but have no idea how to move on.

The guidelines Below in Bold is where i am having issues

Determine the beginning of the next month.  Calculate the last day of the month by doing the following: Get the next month date, now get the previous day of that next month.  Print the Calendar heading for the full month name and year.  Print the header row that contains the abbreviated name of the days of the week.  Create an array with a length of 7 and a default value of 4 spaces (" ").
**Using the date range from the beginning of the month to the end of the month do the following:**

Get the numerical representation of the day of the week using the" %w" formatter and convert to an integer. (This will be the index to the array.)
**Use the index to set the day of the month within the array, using the "%d" formatter to get the day of the month.** 
**If index equals 6 OR the date equals the last day of the month, then do the following:** 
**Loop through the array** 
**Print the day of the month** 
**Print a blank line  Re-initialize the array so that all values are of 4 spaces**

```
def printMonth(year, month)
  now= Date.new(year, month, 1)
  a= now >> 1 
  b= a - 1    
  puts("Calendar for: #{b.strftime("%B, %Y")}")
  puts("")
  puts("Sun\tMon\tTue\tWed\tThu\tFri\tSat")
  days= Array.new(7,"    ")

  c= b.strftime("%w").to_i
end
```

Comment: Last day of the month: `puts Date.new(2017,4,-1)` # => 2017-04-30

Comment: @steenslag: That's cool, I didn't know that.